# Sending large strings using sockets - java

Tags: java, string, sockets, server, client

what i'm trying to do is send strings larger than 60Kb which cannot be sent with WriteUTF method using DataOutputStream

so basically, was i already done with searching and adding my own knowledge to it was converting the string to bytes using getBytes("UTF-8") method and to convert it back to string i used new String("UTF-8") but when i start sending data to my server ( which has to response me back with an string which is also converted to bytes using the same tec) after it prepares streams (DataInputStream and DataOutputStream) they while loop for reading the data never ends

My Server:

```
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new 
DataInputStream(sslSocket.getInputStream());
                        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new 
DataOutputStream(sslSocket.getOutputStream());

                        byte[] bdata = new byte[1024];

                        while(dataInputStream.read(bdata, 0 , bdata.length) > 0){
                            returnData.append(new String(bdata, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
                        }

                        String command = returnData.toString();
                        dataOutputStream.write(returnData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, returnData.toString().getBytes().length);
```

My Client:

```
        dataOutputStream.write(command.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, command.getBytes().length);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while(dataInputStream.read(data, 0, data.length) > 0){
            stringBuilder.append(new String(data, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        }
And then use stringBuilder.toString() to get the data out of the builder.
```

can't really understand why but here's my code, i hope you can help me out with this:

Comment: writeUTF writes a string length before writing the characters, specifically so the receiving end knows how many characters to read.  Perhaps you should do the same.  (Also, `dataOutputStream.write(command.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, command.getBytes().length);` is converting command to bytes in two different ways:  once with UTF-8, once with the platform’s default encoding.  Try just `dataOutputStream.write(command.getBytes("UTF-8"));` instead.)

Comment: Don't use DataOutputStream/DataInputStream to send and receive strings. Don't convert individual byte blocks to strings. Multibyte characters can lead to errors when the character's first byte is in one block and the second byte in the next block.  Use a OutputStreamWriter/InputStreamReader to handle string to byte conversion and BufferedReader/BufferedWriter for buffering and maybe a PrintWriter.

Comment: @vanje Should i first convert my String to a char array then write it , am i right? (using OutputStreamWriter) and reverse for InputStreamReader

Comment: Wrap your OutputStreamWriter with a PrintWriter and use the print() or println() methods. You can pass your strings as is and let all the conversion details to be done by the underlying Writer and Stream implementations.